# Is it feasible for a project manager to work reduced schedule for a a few months?

Tags: planning, time-management, schedule

A project manager's demands can be varying and unpredictable at times. Could somebody offer feedback on how to make a reduced schedule (like 30 hours) workable and successful ?

Comment: As written, this is too broad and invites opinion. Please add some detail about the specific problem you're facing, such as why you're finding it difficult to manage your project portfolio within whatever number of hours you care to allocate.

Comment: Take a look at the Tips for Part Timers in this article. [Want Better Work-Life Balance? Negotiate Reduced Hours](http://www.urban.org/uploadedpdf/lewis-parttime082405.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

Many project managers can handle multiple projects, so by implication, they are working a reduced schedule on each project. It is therefore both practical and effective to do this. But there are areas that need careful handling.

1. Ensure the role is clearly defined. Manage the project, but don't get dragged into the fine detail. Concentrate on the things that really make a difference - planning, governance, reporting, finances, and such like.
2. Manage your diary. Ensure that the project team knows when you are available, and when you are not. Arrange your day so that you have time to do what you have to, and be ruthless about declining meetings that you don't need to attend.
3. Demand that your team provide the level of reports that you need, in the format that you need them. Instil this discipline from day 1, and refuse to compromise.
4. Learn to delegate - but only those things that don't put the project at risk.

The team may not like having a part-time PM, and your managers may also be concerned about this. However, if you can establish the rules, demonstrate success in the early days, and keep up with the paperwork, you will have achieved what you desire.

And always remember that a committed PM working part time is likely to be better than a full-time PM who stares out of the window all day long without adding any real value or drive to the project.

Good luck!